# Query result in field mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this pipeline:

```
pipelines.push({
  $match: getServiceFilters(serviceOne),
});

pipelines.push({
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          //'$$ROOT',
          { s1: '$$ROOT' },
        ],
      },
    },
  }
});
```

So after request, all my results wrapped in "s1" field. It works. But i think i doing it wrong.
How to properly make request and wrap result in "s1" field? I need most optimised way, or any available, so i can test performance in a lot of data.

Comment: That seems fine, what makes you say that you're doing it wrong?

Comment: @user20042973 In the final query, I use a table join, the second table is added to the "s2" field. Then I do calculations in an array of pipelines. The result of these calculations takes ~700ms. Now, I add replaceRoot and this request takes ~820ms.